# looping over different folders python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to use a txt.file for an operation and each txt.file has the same name but is in different subfolders. I tried to make a list with containing the folder name and call with os.chdir, but this does not work.

```
folderlist=["folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4"]
i=0
for i in range(4):

    os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/folderlist[i]")
    file=pd.read_table('file.txt',sep=',',header=0, index_col=None)
 #do something 
 #move to next one 
 i=i+1
```

Comment: The iteration variable `i` is defined in the headline of the loop `for i ...`. You do not have to declare and define it before the loop and do not have to increment it inside the body of the loop. Python also has a nice feature in loops like @HadiFarah is showing in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/folder{}".format(i))
```

if your folder names are folder1, folder2, ...

but if you want to access the strings in the list:

```
for i in folderlist
    os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{}".format(i))
```

if you want to see your "folderlist" inside you can also add (a bit redundant) but:

```
for i in folderlist
    os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{folderlist_i}".format(folderlist_i = i))
```

[string format() function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format)

Example:

```
some_list = ['this', 'is', 'some', 'list']

for i in range(0,5):
    print(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{folderlist_i}".format(folderlist_i = i))

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

for i in some_list:
    print(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{folderlist_i}".format(folderlist_i = i))
```

Output:

```
//Desktop/foldersforreading/0
//Desktop/foldersforreading/1
//Desktop/foldersforreading/2
//Desktop/foldersforreading/3
//Desktop/foldersforreading/4
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//Desktop/foldersforreading/this
//Desktop/foldersforreading/is
//Desktop/foldersforreading/some
//Desktop/foldersforreading/list
```

Comment: is there a way to this with using the defined folderlist ? since this is taking each first file and looking, I would like to see which folder name is used and use the foldername also later for the doing

Comment: yes check the second format, basically `{}` in your string would be formatted to whatever variable you have inside the `format()` function. When you loop over elements in `folderlist` then `os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{}".format(i))` means `os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/{{ whatever i is in your python code }})` which is over every loop iteration one iterator of folderlist.

Comment: @utahpyml would it help if I include an example ?

Comment: yeah an example would be really helpful. Because I get the message no such directory found: folderforreading/0

Comment: @utahpyml because you need to loop over elements: `for i in folderlist` instead of using 'range()'. The point is `{}` is very versatile and will include any variable into your string whether it was string (in case of looping over elements in folderlist) or integer / float (in case you loop over a range of integers)

Comment: @I got it really nice solution !

Answer (score 0):

```
folderlist=["folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4"]
#i=0 #unneeded counter
for i in range(4):

    os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading/"+folderlist[i])
    #os.chdir(r"//Desktop/foldersforreading"+"//"+folderlist[i]) #Alternative if above fails
    file=pd.read_table('file.txt',sep=',',header=0, index_col=None)
 #do something 
 #move to next one 
 #i=i+1 #Commented out since you don't need to iterate your counter
```

Give the above code a try, it should fix your problem and be of simple syntax similar to what you requested.

Comment: I get an error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @utahpyml You're right! My mistake, I tested the code a bit and ran into the same issue.  You were right with using `for i in range(4):`.  Switching the code back to that should fix your problem (As it has for me).  I've updated my code.